# Catch typing mistakes in the database Oracle

Tags: database, oracle

We are importing an external excel files to our SQL database but we need to do some integrity checks using sql script

Here is my sample data

```
Row_no   Student_area Student_subject              Code
    1       Science       Science and Tech             ABC
    2      Science        Science and Teck             ABC
    3       Arts          Pschycolgy                   DEF
    4      Arts          Pscycology                   DEF
```

I need to identifythe anomalies

How do I do that?

Cheers

Comment: use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box on highlighted text to format as code/data/output. Also, you'll need to improve your Q. Add a 2nd block of data showing your required output. And finally, S.O. isn't a free coding service, you're expected to show an attempt to solve your problem. Any code is better than no code at all. At least a discussion of trade-offs would show some effort on your part. ....

Comment: Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: You check for anomalies by writing SQL scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle SQL has many neat features but it does not exhibit human style intelligence (yet). So it cannot identify "anomalies" in data. We must declare the rules for correctness.

In your case you need to define a set of correct values, preferably as reference data tables:

```
 create table student_area (student_area varchar2(30));
 insert into student_area values ('Science');
 insert into student_area values ('Arts');
 create table student_subject (student_area varchar2(30), 
                                student_subject  varchar2(128),
                                subject_code varchar2(3));
 insert into student_subject values ('Science', 'Science and Tech', 'ABC');
 insert into student_subject values ('Arts', 'Psychology', 'DEF');
```

Now you are ready to evaluate the contents of your file. The easiest way to do this is to convert the Excel file to CSV and build an external table over it. This is a special type of table where the data resides in an external OS file rather than in the database. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/et_concepts.htm#g1017623).

If you create an external table with a column mapped to every column in the spreadsheet you can identify the anomalies like this:

```
select * from external_table ext
where ext.student_area not in ( select s.student_area
                                from student_area s )
/

select * from external_table ext
where (ext.student_area, ext.student_subject) not in 
                  ( select s.student_area, s.student_subject
                                from student_subject s )
/
```

Comment: What if the table is really big with 7 different columns and it needs to be manually maintained by the business